# Reloading the page after submitting POST in a browser

Tags: javascript, forms, post, xpages

I have an XPage which uses JQuery dialog where I have a button (inside a plain div nothing with JQuery) which creates a new backend "part" when triggered. On the other hand, on the client-side there's validation(which checks that all fields aren't empty). If client-side validation succeed, server-side executes back-end code and new "part" gets created. The problem I've encountered is when new part gets created, if I hit F5 button, browser offers me to repeat the request. If the user clicks "Yes", new part(which is the duplicate of the last one in form) gets created. How do I prevent it?

```
<xp:button id="save_part_btn"
                        value="+Add part" style="float:right;">
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="complete">
                        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var estdoc:NotesDocument=database.getDocumentByUNID(doc_source.getDocument().getParentDocumentUNID())
var estPartdoc:NotesDocument=estdoc.getParentDatabase().createDocument()

estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Form','Estimate_Cost_Part')
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Predoc',estdoc.getUniversalID())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('$OSN_IsSaved','1')

estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Title', getComponent('input_part_title').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('TSNB_Title',getComponent('input_tsnb_title').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('TSNB_All',getComponent('input_tsnb_all').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('TSNB_Build_Work',getComponent('input_tsnb_build_work').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('TSNB_Equipment',getComponent('input_tsnb_equipment').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('TSNB_Other_Costs',getComponent('input_tsnb_other_costs').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('TSNB_PIR',getComponent('input_tsnb_pir').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('TSNB_Return',getComponent('input_tsnb_return').getValue())

estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Current_Title',getComponent('input_current_title').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Current_All',getComponent('input_current_all').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Current_Build_Work',getComponent('input_current_build_work').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Current_Equipment',getComponent('input_current_equipment').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Current_Other_Costs',getComponent('input_current_other_costs').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Current_PIR',getComponent('input_current_pir').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Current_NDS',getComponent('input_current_nds').getValue())
estPartdoc.replaceItemValue('Current_Return',getComponent('input_current_return').getValue())

//var estPartOdoc=new OsnovaUI_document(estPartdoc)
//estPartOdoc.makeDependent(estdoc)

print('new part created with id:'+estPartdoc)
estPartdoc.makeResponse(estdoc)
estPartdoc.save() 


var ag:NotesAgent=database.getAgent('User_CalculateEstimateCost')
ag.runOnServer(doc_source.getDocument().getNoteID())

}]]></xp:this.action>
```

Server-side code, nothing really special.
On `submit = "true"` I return true if validation succeeds, false if fails

Comment: Some code would be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement the POST-Redirect-GET pattern. Here's an example (from 2010): [XPages: Avoid saving duplicate documents on browser refresh](http://dontpanic82.blogspot.dk/2010/06/xpages-avoid-saving-duplicate-documents.html).

The crucial part is to include a redirect at the end of your server-side logic. Here's a simple example:

```
context.redirectToPage(view.getPageName());
```

In your case the redirect needs to reopen the document so do this:

```
context.redirectToPage(view.getPageName()+ "?OpenXpage&documentId="+doc_source.getNoteID());
```

Comment: I suppose this way would work, but onpageLoad I use `getDocumentByUNID` but it gives me exception back. Is there any another way?

Comment: Please add your onPageLoad logic to your question.

Comment: `var logdoc:NotesDocument=doc_source.getDocument()
var objdoc:NotesDocument=logdoc.getParentDatabase().getDocumentByUNID(logdoc.getParentDocumentUNID())`
Exception occurs on the 2nd line

Comment: So the doc_source data source is invalid when you use context.redirectToPage(view.getPageName());. You need to match the redirect to your case. Here's another example that might work: context.redirectToPage(view.getPageName()+ "?action=openDocument&documentId="+doc_source.getNoteID());

Comment: `context.redirectToPage(view.getPageName()+ "?OpenXpage&documentId="+doc_source.getNoteID());` Worked! Thank you very much!